# Sqlite schema for android application

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application that queries various statistics from a static on-phone database about cars, such as acceleration, engine displacement, doors, etc. I need to specify the format of the database from the client. The UI needs to be able to show a sorted list of information for a particular attribute from multiple cars, such as engine displacement, or cost, AND another view that shows all the attributes for a particular car.

My first thought, rather than creating a table with a column for each attribute: (which is what, 1st normal form?)

```
Cars:
ID - integer primary key
Make - text
Model - text
HorsePower - Real
Acceleration - Real
Doors - INteger
etc..
```

Do this instead:

```
Cars
ID - integer primary key
Make - text
Model - text

CarAttributes:
ID - integer primary key
DisplayName - Text   (that gets shown as a column header, or for a line)
Unit - Text (a short unit suffix that gets appended to the value such as mph)

Values:
ID - integer primary key
CarID - foreign key
CarAttributeID - foreign key
Value - Real
```

This allows the view, given the CarID and the AttributeID to perform a couple queries and just display the results. With the first form, the view would have to somehow know what units/display name goes with what columns.

Is this a reasonable way to request they send me the schema? In other words, if you had a request to provide the data in that schema would you say "ooh gross!"?

Edit: Added example of first schema, and provided more clarity.

Comment: Non related question: Wouldn't it be better to have an online database and make an application that just queries it? That way you can update the data without updating the app?

Comment: @nbarraille - That was actually my first suggestion, but they want it bundled with the application so that relying on a data connection will not be necessary.

Comment: Makes sense. Best way to go then (IMO) is both online and local databases, and update the local one when the app is running with network available.

Comment: @nbarraille - Thanks! I guess my question isn't so much about where the database resides, but more IF the database resides on the phone, is there anything wrong with having a schema more like 3rd-normal-form rather than 1st-normal-form.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Android, but I've worked in automotive aftermarket database publishing.  Typically the feature-attributes are attached as child records to the SubModel entity, and you have something like this:

```
MAKERS
makerid int
makername varchar

MODELS  (e.g. Honda Accord)
modelid int    
makerid int
modelname varchar  

SUBMODEL (e.g. Honda Accord Sedan, Honda Accord Coupe)
submodelid
modelid
submodeldescription
 yearintroduced

MAJORSYSTEM
majorsystemid
majorsystemname varchar

FEATURE
featureid   int
featuredesc varchar
majorsystemid int

SUBMODELFEATURES
submodelid int
year int
featureid int
```

In a OODBMS, you can have MODELFEATURES and allow them to be overridden at the SUBMODEL level, just like class inheritance.